# How do I add a routing rule or redirect for the root URL using the s3_website gem?

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I've tried to redirect the root URL of my S3-hosted website (built in Jekyll, deployed using the s3_website gem), but haven't had any success.

My goal in the following example is to redirect http://www.example.com/ to http://www.example.com/redirect_to_here/ using s3_website's routing features.

Here are two routing rule variations I've tried without any luck:

```
routing_rules:
  - condition:
      key_prefix_equals: "" # Empty prefix
    redirect:
      host_name: www.example.com
      replace_key_prefix_with: redirect_to_here/
      http_redirect_code: 302
```

and

```
routing_rules:
  - condition:
      key_prefix_equals: /
    redirect:
      host_name: www.example.com
      replace_key_prefix_with: redirect_to_here/
      http_redirect_code: 302
```

Is this possible given S3's redirect implementation? If so, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than resorting to the `routing_rules` and remembering that S3 treats index.html as the root path, the following ended up working. Specifically I used `redirects` rather than `routing_rules` to achieve this:

```
# s3_website.yml
redirects:
  index.html: /redirect_to_here/
```

Comment: Quick note -- `index.html` is the _default_ index document. So if you've changed it for your deployment (eg. to `foo.bar`), simply update the redirect to reflect this.